# AFNetworking framework : how to cache image

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

```
-(void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url,
```

the method in AFNetworking described: "**If the image is cached locally, the image is set immediately**", but it does not make me to set cache directory, so where it cache the image in? Or is it really cache the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AFNetworking` takes advantage of the caching functionality already provided by `NSURLCache` and any of its subclasses.

Use [Pete Steinberger's fork of SDURLCache](https://github.com/steipete/SDURLCache) which provides disk caching, which is not otherwise implemented by `NSURLCache` on `iOS`.

**Note**: as of `iOS5`, this is no longer needed. `NSURLCache` now properly `caches objects`, as long as the `Cache-Control` `header` is `set`.

You may find it useful to `set ignoreMemoryOnlyStoragePolicy` to `YES` for the `SDURLCache` instance, which will ensure that images will be cached to disk more consistently for offline use (which, as reported in the SDURLCache README, iOS 5 supports, but only for http, so it still remains a good option if you want to support iOS 4 or https)

Refer [AFNetworking-FAQ - Does AFNetworking have any caching mechanisms built-in?](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ) and also [AFURLCache - disk cache for iOS](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/25) links.

Comment: According to Pete Steinberger himself: “Note: as of iOS5, this is no longer needed. NSURLCache now properly caches objects, as long as the Cache-Control header is set.”